# Sharepoint Spell Checker for Comment boxes only

Tags: 2007, spellchecker

In my sharepoint application i am using spell checker control for spell checking the entire page. And i excluded the spell checking in People Picker control bu using the folowing snippet.

```
 var pplResponsibleIsValid = (($('#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_pplResponsible').find('*[isresolved="False"]')).length == 0);

if (pplELTResponsibleIsMoreThanOne
return false;
```

But now, my requirement is, i have to exclude all the text boxes except comment box.

Now the System is checking all the text box controls. but I want to remove this functionality and it restrict only to comment box. Please help if you Guys have any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I achieved my goal. when i was went to [this Site](http://kwizcom.blogspot.in/2009/04/want-to-know-how-to-skip-sharepoint.html)

and added this attribute tot he control that i wish to exclude from the functionality of Speeling Checking Control. It's working.